# What does this macro do? __success(return >= 0) long

Tags: visual-c++, annotations, hresult

In the Windows header file WinNT.h, HRESULT is defines as follows:

```
typedef __success(return >= 0) long HRESULT;
```

Doing some research I learned that the "__success" macro is part of the Microsoft source code annotation language **SAL** and is defined in *sal.h*.  But for the life of me I can't figure out what it does or how it does it.

Comment: Seems that this question has already been posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985521/explaining-the-declaration-definition-of-hresult

__success expands to nothing so it doesn't affect the code.  While it may help Microsoft's analysis tools, it really really messes up the readability of the code, in my opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This blog post on MSDN](https://web.archive.org/web/20150701133014/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/staticdrivertools/archive/2008/11/06/annotating-for-success.aspx) explains exactly what `__success` means: it indicates that a function succeeded if it returns a `HRESULT` value >= 0.

Annotations are just a way of describing something about a piece of code - by themselves, they don't "do" anything, but it's possible to have external tools verify the semantics of such annotations.

Comment: I had read the blog post prior to posting my question. The blog is not well-written (suddenly starts talking about a scanner without any definition) and I really could not understand it.

Specifically, what happens if the return code is less than zero?

Comment: @Toddintr: As I mentioned, the annotations by themselves don't change the way your program behaves. But there are tools (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michael_howard/archive/2006/05/19/602077.aspx) that can use these annotations to inspect your code and warn you of possibly incorrect usage.

Comment: FWIW, the link to the MSDN blog post is dead.